# perform parts of function with time space java script

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```
Plus() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('like hintable')[0].click(); Hide();alert ("test") ;
}
```

How could I run `document.getElementsByClassName('like hintable')[0].click()`
after two seconds run `Hide()` after two other seconds run `alert`.

Is there any way without creating 3 functions and use `setTimeOut` .

Comment: Why you cant create 3 functions and use `setTimeOut`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: I'm trying to make code short as possible @Mike

Comment: Creating function for different activity is not a bad practice. U have to create different functions to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use sleep/delay/wait in a function to pause Javascript unfortunately.

You have to use `setTimeout()`

[SO - Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389200/javascript-sleep-delay-wait-function)

[SO - Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)